# can i install Ubuntu14.04 in my ideapad?

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, performance, lenovo

i'm using ubuntu 12.04  64 bit version in my Lenovo S100 ideapad.
my ideapad is having 2GB RAM and Atom processor.Is there any performance and speed problems will occur if i change my OS to 14.04?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the [official system requirements](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements):
700 MHz processor (about Intel Celeron or better)
512 MiB RAM (system memory)
5 GB of hard-drive space (or USB stick, memory card or external drive but see LiveCD for an alternative approach)
VGA capable of 1024x768 screen resolution
Either a CD/DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media
Internet access is helpful

I'd say you are good to go, but really try [xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/), it's also supported by Canonical but it's more light, or [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) (but it's not Canonical supported) that is even more light.They are both Ubuntu compatible.